# Storm Topology: Multiple vs. One

Tags: azure, apache-storm, topology

Devices will send multiple messages to Azure Eventhub (still not decided).
Each message will have different formats and contents (though need different processing).
Each message will contain a unique ServiceID identifying what kind of msg.

We have now two scenarios in mind how to handle it.

a) 
1. Spout will receive msg and pass it to a ParserBolt
2. ParserBolt will read ServiceID and based on the ID pass it to a different bolt

In this case each msg (based on the ServiceID) will go through a different path in the topology. All messages could be handled by one topology.

b)
1. Multiple Topologies - for each ServiceID one.
2. Spout will receive msg and pass it to Bolt
3. Bolt will read ServiceID - if correct serviceID will pass it to the next bolt, if not correct serviceID will dismiss this job

Since Storm guarantees that each msg is processed atleast once - each msg will come at some point to the correct topology. But the topologies will dismiss a lot of messages which were not meant for them.

Comment: Hey Erik, welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is pretty open ended and there isn't a clear answer. Could you rephrase to ask a more specific question? See [here for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot split your input stream outside of Storm, you should definitely go with a single topology. This will save a lot of network traffic and unnecessary data replication.